# git check out arago-project throwing protocol error

Tags: git, proxy, texas-instruments, bitbake

I am trying to checkout arago-project's oe-layersetup using below command.

```
#git clone git://arago-project.org/git/projects/oe-layersetup.git
```

It is throwing error like "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Prox"

But I can able to checkout some other repos using git protocol. It is working fine.
I have setup git proxy. Because I am working under corporate firewall.

```
example: 
#git clone git://github.com/TI-OpenLink/ti-utils.git
```

can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Please find the log below:

```
xxx@xxx:~/tmp/git$ git clone git://arago-project.org/git/projects/oe-layersetup.git
Cloning into 'oe-layersetup'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Prox
xxx@xxx:~/tmp/git$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git clones are working fine without any problem. Make sure you are not using any proxy.

[image]

If you need to use proxy anyways, then check the proxy settings whether it allows http/https as it is the most commonly used protocol.